# Creating a pkg installer for MacOs with the ability to install in the user's home directory

Tags: macos, package, pkgbuild, productbuild, macos-installer

I want to create a pkg file to install the bundle in the user directory (/Users//Applications/).

How can I do it?

I used the product build with the transfer of the file to the product:

`productbuild --component ./Bundle.app --product ./file.plist`

file.plist contains

```
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>home</key>
  <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

But it does not work...

Is it possible to achieve this behavior with
`pkgbuild`
or
`productbuild`
?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to do it.

1. `pkgbuild --root <path to app> --identifier <identifier> --scripts <path to scripts>--install-location Applications/Name.app Package.pkg`
2. `productbuild --synthesize --package ./Package.pkg Distribution.xml`
3. Editing a file Distribution.xml by adding a tag in `installer-gui-script`:
   `<domains enable_anywhere="false" enable_currentUserHome="true" enable_localSystem="false"/>`
4. `productbuild --distribution ./Distribution.xml --package-path ./Package.pkg Product.pkg`